# Help Identify Faulty Component - Dishwasher Controller Board

Tags: relay, troubleshooting

Not sure if this is the right place to post this.

Recently my dishwasher gave away :(. It works fine (goes through wash - rinse cycle)when empty but the moment it is loaded, the display lights go weak and start dying the when it enters the rinse stage.

I was quoted $100 for a replacement board by the repairman. Being semi competent in electronics, I am trying to take a stab at it to see if I can find the faulty component and replace it myself.

Attached are the pictures of the front and the back of the board.

[image]

[image]

My hunch is the black relay in the bottom left as thats the only mechanical component on the board and upon visual inspection, I don't see any obviously burnt components.

Any help would be appreciated on how can I go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry repair questions are off topic here, but if you suspect that part you should take the numbers off the top of it and see if you can find a replacement online.  Just google them one at a time.  Short of that you could probably find online or buy the repair manual for that dishwasher.  It will have pseudo schematics of that board suitable for a technician to try to debug it.  Hopefully you have at least a meter you can use to measure things. Basically you're looking at poking around and trying things until or if you can figure it out.

You might also try ebay for the part.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Though my question was geared towards 'how to find out which is the faulty part'. The relay being bad is just a hunch. But I understand that repair questions are off topic, hence I'll accept this as the answer and close the topic.